# Como calcular una hora a y una hora b con time ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy haciendo una validación que tiene que ser mayor a 4 horas y no sé como hacerlo.

Tengo dos atributos `hora_inicio` y `hora_final`, que pertenecen a `Time`.

En la primera validación:

```
def validar_horas
  if hora_inicio < hora_final

  else
    errors.add(:hora_final,"La hora final de la reunion debe ser mayor a la de hora inicial")      
  end
end
```

La segunda **no** sé cómo se hace, he intentado hacer de todo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La diferencia entre dos instancias de `Time` es un `float` en segundos, de forma que, puedes realizar la comparación siguiente,

```
( hora_final - ( 60 * 60 * 4 ) ) < ( hora_inicio )
```

Comment: if ( hora_final - ( 60 * 60 * 4 ) ) < ( hora_inicio )
   
 else
       
         errors.add(:hora_final,"La hora final de la reunion debe ser mayor a la de hora inicial")
            
   end      yo lo hice así gracias. y no me da

Comment: Quita el _else_ o sustituye el  '<' por '>='

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría de esta forma:

```
if (hora_final - hora_inicio) / 3600 > 4
  # ...
else
  errors.add(:hora_final,"La hora final de la reunion debe ser mayor a la de hora inicial") 
end
```

El código anterior funciona, pero en caso que no vayas a realizar acción alguna  cuando el `if` se cumpla (i.e. `hora_final` sea mayor por 4 horas a `hora_inicial`), entonces te recomendaría invertir la lógica y reducir tu código:

```
if (hora_final - hora_inicio) / 3600 <= 4
  errors.add(:hora_final,"La hora final de la reunion debe ser mayor a la de hora inicial")
end
```

O, en su defecto, utiliza `unless` en lugar de `if`:

```
unless (hora_final - hora_inicio) / 3600 > 4
  errors.add(:hora_final,"La hora final de la reunion debe ser mayor a la de hora inicial") 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Propongo lo siguiente, creo que es más legible.

```
def validar_horas

  if hora_inicio > hora_final - 4.hours
    errors.add(:hora_final, "La hora final de la reunion debe ser al menos 4 horas posterior a la hora inicial")      
  end

end
```

Si consideras que es más claro, puedes la condición al revés:

```
if hora_final - 4.hours < hora_inicio
```

O sumar las cuatro horas al inicio en vez de restarlas al final:

```
if hora_inicio + 4.hours > hora_final
```

Las tres condiciones dan el mismo resultado.